# why my no.of rows are exploding after BroadCast Hash Join

Tags: scala, apache-spark

somehow no.of output rows are exploding after BroadCast Hash Join. right side table has unique row on join column. not sure what causing exploding rows. attaching SQL plan here
[image]

Comment: please attach the text query plan, not the UI.

Comment: Seems like either your code is not doing what you think or your data are not as you think.

Comment: Have you checked which kind of join you perform ? inner ? outer ? cross ?

Comment: Even if the right side is unique, your join condition may be such that each row on the left may match multiple rows on the right.  At minimum give us the join condition.